# Transparent Picturebox Is Transparent Through Drawn Graphics; Want To Show Drawn Graphics

Tags: c#, winforms

I've run into a transparency issue I haven't been able to solve on this custom numberline usercontrol I'm building.

The white area for the numberline is a panel. The black position indicator is an image in a picturebox. The image has proper transparency and the picturebox's backcolor is set to transparent.

When I draw the green target area, using graphics on the panel, the picturebox shows through the drawn area to the panel's backcolor. The picturebox's transparency is working properly- the blue panel background example shows that the picturebox is properly displaying the panel's backcolor.

I want the picturebox to show the drawn graphics through its transparent areas.

Is it possible for the picturebox to let the drawn rectangle show through, or do I have to also draw on the picturebox?

Blue Panel Background: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WCdgq.png

Normal Display: https://i.stack.imgur.com/K90qu.png

Comment: In Winforms there is not __real__ but only __faked Transparency__. It will work __if and only if__ the control is __nested__ in another control. It work by copying the parent's background but your drawn graphics are not part of it so they won't show 'through'. You may succeed by drawing into a bitmap and setting it as the Panel.BackgroundImage and maybe an extra Refresh.. Or maybe simply draw onto the Pbox??

Comment: PictureBox achieves transparency by drawing its Parent content to set its background.  So you can't see the green, you see the panel's color.  True transparency is easy to achieve by layering paint, simply use Graphics.DrawImage() instead of the PictureBox.  Much more efficient as well.

Comment: Following TaW's advice I am drawing a custom bitmap and setting that as the background image for the panel. This is bypassing the issue and everything is working as intended.